# Create transparent background image by slicing in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: image, background, transparent, slice, adobe-illustrator

I have been trying to slice a tansparent background image from a .AI (Adobe illustrator) file. But haven't got any solution yet.

Can somebody please guide me on this? Or providing a tutorial link will be helpful.

Just wanted to tell you tha my concern is Adobe Illustrator (.AI) file. I know how to do the same in Adobe Photoshop. I also know that how to slice images in Adobe Illustrator, The only thing I am looking for is how to slice them with transparent background.

Answer (score 2):

- After slicing, go to *File >> Save For Web & Devices*.
- Select *PNG-24* in the Preset drop-down.
- Check the Transparent check-box *ON*.
- Save

It should give your sliced images as transparent .PNG files.